# Iterating through a list of words to check if any start with a given string in Python

Tags: python, string, list, loops

I've recently starting to learn Python, and everything has seemed reasonably intuitive until now.

I have a text file that has several lines of data on it. I'm iterating through each line, splitting it into words, and I now want to go through each word on a given line to check if it starts with a given string, and then if so, change the word to something else.

So far I have:

```
with open('test_inputfile.txt','r') as f:
for line in f:
    words = line.split('","')
    for word in words:
        if word.startswith('spam'):
            # change given word
```

But this doesn't work as I can't seem to access the `.startswith()` function of `word`.

I'm sure it must be easy to do, as everything else so far has been very straightforward!

Thanks.

Comment: You probably have an empty iterable since you should be splitting on `','` not `'","'`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Not empty, but only one element: the entire `line`.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye the text file has both a comma and double apostrophes between the words

Comment: you probably have a line like `"spam","second","third"` in this case using `","` (both quotes and comma) as separator will produce a different behavior between the first, middle and last element. If you have the quotes as part of text, just use comma as separator and look for `"spam` instead of `spam` in your `startswith` method

Comment: Can you please post a part of your input file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
f = open('test_inputfile.txt').readlines()
f = [i.strip('\n').split(',') for i in f]
for line in f:
    for word in line:
       if word.startswith('spam'):
```

now, f stores a list of lists containing all the words in each row.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably be useful if you are using CSV data. if that is the case change your split to `line.split(',')`. Otherwise see below.

When using the `startswith` function, there is no need to actually split the lines, because you are only interested in what the line starts with. See [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_startswith.htm) for more information on the `startswith` function

`with open('test_inputfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('spam', 0, 4):
            # take action`

This effectively checks if the word 'spam' is in the position 0 to 4

All the best :)

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear, I want to check if each WORD starts with 'spam', not each line.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You might be forgetting to strip the initial/final double quotes in each line. But I strongly recommend using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to process csv data:

```
import csv
with open('test_inputfile.txt','r') as f: 
  reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"') 
  # both params are the default values anyway 
  for row in reader:
    for word in row:
      if word.startswith('spam'):
        # do stuff
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I'm getting the same issue with this as my original code: I can't use the .startswith() function of word

Answer (score 0):

You have a file like this :

```
"toast","eggs","bacon" 
"orangejuice","spamandtoast","bagels"
```

Read the file:

```
with open("test_inputfile.txt", "r") as fs:
    for lines in fs:
        line = lines.split(",")
        for word in line:
            word = word.replace('"','') # removes the quotes
            if word.startswith("spam"):
                print word
```

You can also create an empty list `wordlist = []` in the beginning, and add each word in the list.

`wordlist.append(word)`

Better use [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: This is basically identical my code, but I cannot use 'words.startswith()'.

Comment: Please post a little bit text of your input.

Comment: It looks like this:

`"toast","eggs","bacon"
"orangejuice","spamandtoast","bagels"`

(where `orangejuice` starts a new line)

I want to find `spamandtoast`, and then, for example, change it to `yoghurt`